# typescript build task always failed in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was run vscode in window OS and remove developement in WSL.

here is the tasks.json in vscode

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

and when i try to execute the task, vscode show below error when executing it.

```
 *  Executing task: /home/temp/test/node_modules/.bin/tsc -p /home/temp/test/tsconfig.json 

/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

 *  The terminal process "/usr/bin/bash '-c', '/home/temp/test/node_modules/.bin/tsc -p /home/temp/test/tsconfig.json'" failed to launch (exit code: 127). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

here is the package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.4.2"
  }
}
```

could someone can help me out?

i was tried with instruction from offical document here.

[instruction](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

but don't know why this is not work in my local

Comment: have you installed NodeJS to your system and is it on your system PATH?

Comment: @starball thanks, yes, in WSL, i have install the nodejs via NVM, and this `/home/temp/test/node_modules/.bin/tsc -p /home/temp/test/tsconfig.json` can be execute successfully in terminal.